# How to set a default quantity in Bundle Product

Tags: bundled-product, quantity, product-edit

Here I am trying to pre-populate **bundle product** `quantity` in bundle edit page. I tried to add a default value but its not working.

[image]

here my code sample.

/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/BundlePanel.php

```
'selection_qty' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'component' => 'Magento_Bundle/js/components/bundle-option-qty',
                                'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                                'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                                'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                                'label' => __('Default Quantity'),
                                'dataScope' => 'selection_qty',
                                'value' => '1',
                                'default' => 1,
                                'sortOrder' => 100,
                                'validation' => [
                                    'required-entry' => true,
                                    'validate-number' => true,
                                    'validate-greater-than-zero' => true
                                ],
                                'imports' => [
                                    'isInteger' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.selection_qty_is_integer'
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
```

Where am doing wrong. Can I get some help?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution.

```
vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/bundle-option-qty.js
```

by adding this function in above file

```
setInitialValue:function(){
            this.initialValue=this.getInitialValue();
            if(this.initialValue===undefined||this.initialValue===''){
                this.initialValue=1;
            }
```